# When does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\cos(n)\cdot z^n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis

> When does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\cos(n)\cdot z^n}$ converge or diverge?

I tried finding a divergent series to compare it to but failed. I know that $\cos$ oscillates between $-1,1$. But this does not help me sadly, any ideas?

Comment: Obviously it converges for $|z|<1$. For $|z|>1$ you probably expect it to diverge, but you have to be a bit careful about how reliably $n$ can be close to $\pi/2 + \pi \mathbb{Z}$, which has to do with the irrationality measure of $\pi$. For $|z|=1$ I somewhat doubt that this is an easy problem at all.

Comment: @Ian Is it realistic to consider $$\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|\cos (n)|}?$$

Comment: Well, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |\cos(n)| =1,$ since you when $\frac{n}{q}$ is a continued fraction for $\pi$ you have $\left|\frac{n}{q}-\pi\right|<\frac{1}{q^2},$ and thus $|n-q\pi|<\frac{1}{q}.$ so $n$ is close enough to a multiple of $\pi$ to have $\cos(n)$ close to $\pm 1.$

Comment: For $|z| \ge1$ the terms do not converge to zero...

Comment: I think that @Crostul is on the right track. I mean, since $\{\cos(n):n=0,1,\ldots\}$ is a dense subset of $[-1,1]$, we may find a subsequence of $\cos(n)z^n$  that diverges, for $|z|\geq1$.

Comment: @Bach It's well known that $\{e^{in}\}$ is dense in the circle.

Comment: @Bach $\{e^{in}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is dense in the unit circle. This is essentially the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: Indeed @Crostul has it right, though for $|z|=1$ you might have a more interesting problem on your hands if you try Cesaro summation instead. Sorry I muddied the waters with my first comment...